# Django ,Facebook Graph API and iOS

Tags: python, ios, django

I am completely new in this field and I am building an iOS application using django on my server and need some suggestions and help how to go about it. I am writing web services using django-tastypie. The user authentication for the app is using the facebook iOS sdk. Post that the Unique ID given by facebook is sent to my server to access public data from their profile using Facebook-Graph API and stored in my database on the server. I am using ASIHTTPRequest library for handling HTTP requests from the application to the server. Please tell me if my approach is correct and if possible help me with some links which can help me for the same.

Answer (score 2):

I've found [Pyfb](https://github.com/jmg/pyfb) to be a great timesaver for projects utilizing Facebook Graph API.